# How to perform calculations on nested form items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am fairly new to Rails and I have these two models...

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items      
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
  ...
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  def self.total
    price * quantity
  end
  ...
end
```

... and a nested (!) form that creates new invoice records and their associated items.

However, I find it very difficult to perform calculations on these items. For example next to each item I would like to put the `total` for this item using the `total` method above.

Unfortunately, it's not working. In my form I put this next to each item:

```
<%= @invoice.items.amount %>
```

which is derived from my controller:

```
def new      
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  3.times {@invoice.items.build}
end
```

It keeps throwing an error saying `undefined local variable or method price`

What am I missing here??

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a class method on Item, when I think what you want is an instance method.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  def total
    price * quantity
  end
  ...
end
```

which you can call on an individual item `@item.total` or, if you do you the total of all the items, then you'd need to do something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  def self.total
    all.collect { |item| item.price * item.quantity }
  end
  ...
end
```

`@invoice.items.total`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get this to work in a nested form that posts to two models. It keeps telling me that there's no method "total" even though I defined it just as you said.

Comment: Please edit your OP to show the object that you are trying to call total on.

Comment: OK, I probably didn't describe the problem very well. I just re-posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505453/how-to-call-a-method-on-an-object-in-a-nested-form-in-ruby-on-rails-3).