# How to call a method on an object in a nested form in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have these two models

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items      
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
  ...
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  def total
    price * quantity
  end
  ...
end
```

and this nested (!) form that posts to both models:

```
<h1>Add an Invoice</h1>
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :recipient %>
  <%= f.text_field :recipient %> </p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :date %>
  <%= f.text_area :date %>
</p>
<h2>Items</h2>
<p>
  <%= f.fields_for(:items) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
    <%= f.label :quantity %>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
    <%= f.label :total %>
    <%= f.total %><!-- this method call is not working! -->
  <% end %>
</p>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

How can I do calculations on my items within the form?

In my `Items` model I have this method:

```
def total
  price * quantity
end
```

However, in the form I can't get it to work with `f.total`. I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `total' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x10ec05558>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a method not on your model object, but on `f`, which is a form helper (`ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`). Error message gives a hint to this.

To call on the item, you need to replace

```
<%= f.total %>
```

with

```
<%= f.object.total %>
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks a lot! Quite tricky these nested forms...